# How to create SQL Server Version control in Dev Ops Azure

Tags: sql-server, git, azure, azure-devops

I am a 1 man team, more dev's coming on board, I have created a few on Premise SQL DBs; I have a Azure SQL DB managed instance and Azure Devops account setup

**Currently:**
I use SSDT -->Tools--> SQL Server:  to manage the data and Schema comparisons , make sure it is in sync, On-Premise and Azure managed instance (as a backup at present, managed instance is not used for anything else)

**I want to do**
To manage the code for multiple devs,

- I want to setup  Azure SQL DB   managed instance as production
- SSDT or Git hub for version control(manage check-in / check out of SQL objects, we are all in sync)
- Local on premise version as the development area, sync in with prod, use TFVC (SSDT) as tool to manage
  the code conflicts , make sure all devs are working off the same DB

Q: Can I link my on premise SQL DB to DevOps source control , then links to SQL Azure managed DB? Can I do this with SSDT / GIT hub or do I need both?

Any step by step tutorials to set this up? In SSDT I am connected to my on premise SL db and to DevOps Repo , finding it difficult to figure out how to establish the link between the two

Getting overwhelmed with all the acronyms and 101 different products you can use (state based approach, DACPAC files, YAML , arm template , octopus deploy, redgate, dacfx,)

Cannot find anything online so far to show me how to setup from the ground up

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Can I link my on premise SQL DB to DevOps source control , then links to SQL Azure managed DB? Can I do this with SSDT / GIT hub or do I need both?

You have to install a self-hosted agent to access your on-premises instances

Then the pipeline flow can be built this way:

**Build DacPac** -> **Deploy to Test** (On-Premises) -> **Deploy to Managed Instance (Prod)**

Other points:

Since you are starting a new project, consider to use YAML pipelines.

Also, SSDT, starting VS 2019, is not suitable anymore for free use in a commercial environment. You have to get Professional or Enterprise license.
As the alternative, cross-platform Azure Data Studio + Database Project add-on

And some of the concepts blogged by me earlier:

- https://www.alexvolok.com/2020/azure-devops-sql-server-dba-creating-database-project/
- https://www.alexvolok.com/2020/azure-devops-for-sql-server-dba-automating-deployments/